# Reload all js file after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here in my project i am using ajax to change the content of a div on click of button.

Here is my code :

```
  $('#geo_location').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: '/get_geo_locations/',
        type: 'GET',

        success: function(response){

            currentPage.getTemplateOnly('/static/template/geo_location.html', function(template){
                $('#dataset_container').html(template({
                    geo_location: response
                }));

     $('#dataset_about').html('...')

            });
        }
```

But i need some js file to be reloaded as it loads on page refresh.

And i am able to change the content but style that is implemented because of some js file is not applicable.

How i can do that ?

Comment: it would be better if you figure out exactly what needs to be re-ran in your js file(s) and run it again. Failing that, you could try just adding a new script include on the page for the same file, though this may or may not break things, depending on what's in the file.. but there's no way to "reload" a js file in the sense of "pretend it wasn't loaded in the first place and load it"

Comment: I had a similar issue on Yii using star rating, I ended up having to reload the page as I just couldn't figure out why my starts wouldn't render by reloading only a section of the page...

Comment: ..or you could try refactoring the code in your js file(s) to handle new content.. for example if you have js that hooks something to a link or whatever, you could attach the handler to a parent element that always exists so that event delegation will occur. But it really depends on what exactly you need to have happen.

Comment: @CrayonViolent I have figured out what js file is needed to change the style and i have used `$.getScript('/static/js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js', function() {...})` but its also not helping me

Comment: window.location.reload(true); is this what you mean?

Comment: but if i will do it it will change my div content also. I am asking about isnt there something so that we can reload js file only